# How to create a visualization for a timer job

Tags: c#, silverlight-5.0

In my SL application I have a `DispatchTimer` which periodically refreshes data on the screen. I would like to create a visualisation for the user to show when the next refresh will happen.

My first thought was to change the timer (which currently runs every 20 seconds) to run every millisecond and, each tick, update a `ProgressBar` and count-down till the 20 seconds are up to run the main update method.

But I cannot shake the feeling that there's probably a better way of doing this. This feels quite heavy.

IS there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make an animated progress bar which resets on reaching the end.
Easiest would be to create two rectangles, one on top of antother with different colors.
Animate width of the one on the top from 0 to length of your progress bar.
You can control it by making a property which indicates how long should the animation last.
And maybe some start method to synchronize with refresh actions.

EDIT. There is example on msdn [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.windows.controls.progressbar.aspx) (examples section)

Comment: This was my other idea. But why go through the trouble of creating rectangles? I can use a normal progress bar - I could, in theory at least, create the animation by manipulating the `Progress` property?

Comment: Yes, I think it might be possible. I edited my answer.

Comment: This looks nice. My only question is... how do I hook this up when using a MVVM programming model? The model has the timer and performs the updates. Setting up a property which contains the "time until refresh" percentage is easy. I'm not so sure on how to trigger the animation on the UI however. I admit - I've never played with animations triggered by models before.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of a progres bar is not that bad. Updating every milisecond or each tick is much to often. 10 times a second would be enough.